# In filtering a pandas dataframe on multiple conditions, is df[condition1][condition2] equivelant to df[(condition1) & (condition2)]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

Say you have a pandas dataframe df with columns `df['year']`, `df['fish']`, and `df['age']`. In practice (in pandas version 0.22.0), it appears that

`df[df['year']<2000][df['fish']=='salmon'][df['age']!=50]`

yields results identical to

`df[(df['year']<2000) & (df['fish']=='salmon') & (df['age']!=50)]`

However, in tutorials and other stackoverflow questions I only see the second version (the one with boolean operators) recommended. Is that just because it's more flexible and can do other boolean operators, or are there situations in which these two methods do not yield the same result?

Comment: The second example is definitely more readable, as well as allowing you to use the | operator (or). I couldn't say for certain if there are situations where the two provide different results though. I'm assuming the second approach probably runs a little faster too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why you should not do df[condition1][condition2]

You should go with the second approach. In addition to the greater readability of the second version, the first approach can lead to warnings as the dataframe that is returned by the first selection operation might not contains all the indices provided during the second selection.

For instance, let's consider this dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,0,1,0], 'b': [0,0,0,1,1]})
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  0
3  1  1
4  0  1
```

And test for equality to `1` on both columns (the example is trivial) with `df['a'].eq(1)` and `df['b'].eq(1)`. Both return Series of True/False with all the indices of df:

```
>>> df['a'].eq(1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

>>> df['b'].eq(1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

But after the first slicing `df[df['a'].eq(1)]` you get:

```
   a  b
1  1  0
3  1  1
```

Thus the second selection tries to use indices that are absent and you get a warning:

```
>>> df[df['a'].eq(1)][df['b'].eq(1)]
   a  b
3  1  1

UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  df[df['a'].eq(1)][df['b'].eq(1)]
```

#### How you can sometimes do better than df[condition1 & condition2]

When you do `df[condition1 & condition2]`, both tests are done prior to selecting the data. This can be unnecessary if computation of condition2 is expensive.

Let's consider the following example where column `a` is mostly 0s with a few 1s:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.choice([0,1], size=100, p=[0.9, 0.1]),
                   'b':  np.random.choice([0,1], size=100)
                  })
```

```
    a   b
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   1
... 
95  0   1
96  0   1
97  0   0
98  0   0
99  0   1
```

and consider this (stupid) expensive function to apply on the second column, that inefficiently checks whether the values are equal to 1:

```
def long_check(s):
    import time
    out = []
    for elem in s:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        out.append(elem == 1)
    return out
```

Now, if we do `df[df['a'].eq(1) & long_check(df['b'])]`, we get the expected result (rows with only 1s), but it takes 1s to run (10ms per row × 100 rows).

```
    a  b
1   1  1
33  1  1
34  1  1
50  1  1
52  1  1
```

We can make it much more efficient by first selecting first on condition1, saving the intermediate result, and then selecting on condition2.

```
df2 = df[df['a'].eq(1)]
df2[long_check(df2['b'])]
```

The result is exactly the same but now the expensive function runs only on the rows selected by the first condition (10 rows instead of 100). It is thus 10 times faster.

Comment: Thank you! Two questions about your answer:
1. Why does `df['a'][df['a'].eq(1)][df['b'].eq(1)]` not raise a warning?
2. Although a warning is raised and reindexing happens behind the scenes (both of which I agree are bad, and dangerous if pandas changes in future versions), `df[df['a'].eq(1)][df['b'].eq(1)]` does ultimately yield the exact same result as `df[(df['a'].eq(1)) & (df['b'].eq(1))]`. Are there situations in which this is not the case? I ask in order to evaluate the risk of errors in past work that utilized `df[df['a'].eq(1)][df['b'].eq(1)]`.

Comment: 1. I think because df['a'] is a Series, not a DataFrame (see the source of [pandas/core/frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py) where the warning is generated). 2. it should be fine as pandas is taking care of reindexing for you (again, see the source), but don't do it in future code ;)